# awk is putting last column in a new line

Tags: awk, columns

I have this

```
    -77.199997 23.6343749630 39.9989584580 
    -80.000000 23.6364583430 39.9989584580
    -81.599998 23.6385417220 39.9989584580
```

I want to reorder the columns so it reads column 2, column 3, column 1 (lat,long,elevation)

I have used awk many times before but for some reason when reordering the columns, it comes out like this, with an extra space

```
     32.1614584410 43.3385414490
     -2019.400024 
     32.1635418210 43.3385414490
     -2016.800049 
     32.1656252000 43.3385414490
     -2018.500000
```

I have many more but could someone tell me as to why its doing this or am I missing something

```
    awk -F" " '{print " "$2" "$3" "$1" "}' infile.xyz > outfile.xyz
    awk '{print $2 $3 $1}' infile.xyz > outfile.xyz
    awk -F" " '{print ""$2" "$3" "$1""}' infile.xyz > outfile.xyz
```

Comment: `awk '{print $2,$3,$1}' infile`...

Comment: It could be that `infile.xyz` is carriage return terminated. Run dos2unix on it first

Comment: Sweet, dos2unix worked. Never had to do that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run dos2unix on all the infiles and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: +1, I, too, had the same problem due to Windows style line endings. Piping the input and adding   perl -p -e 's/\r$//'   worked for me (which essentially like running dos2unix on infiles)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using *spaces* and not *tabs* in the input file.

Then, try separating the variables by commas, like this:

```
awk '{print $2,$3,$1}' infile.xyz > output.xyz
```

If you place the variables side by side, like in `$2 $3 $1`, `awk` concatenates them.

Also, you may want to try the `printf` function, as it provides better formatting capabilities.